# power bi dax for loop

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: example]

Hello Everyone,

I have a dataset in Power BI that I want manipulate. I want to create a new column (or perhaps a measure would be best) called "Left Over". Basically, for each year-month, I want to take the difference of Created and Closed. Which will fill the first spot of "Left Over". Then add that "Left Over"[i] to created and do the same process of taking the difference.

In pseudo-code it looks like this:

```
for year-month:
    Left Over = (Left Over[i-1] + Created[i]) - Closed[i]
```

I am not sure how to do this since Dax does not have for loops...can someone help me >.<

Copiable text below:

| Year | Month | Created | Closed | Left Over |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Jan | 10 | 9 | 1 |
| 2019 | Jan | 20 | 10 | 11 |
| 2019 | Feb | 25 | 10 | 26 |
| 2019 | Apr | 40 | 30 | 36 |
| 2019 | Mar | 30 | 15 | 51 |
| 2020 | May | 12 | 10 | 53 |
| 2020 | Jun | 15 | 15 | 53 |
| 2020 | Jul | 20 | 15 | 58 |
| 2020 | Sept | 20 | 10 | 68 |
| 2021 | Feb | 60 | 35 | 93 |
| 2021 | Apr | 45 | 35 | 103 |
| 2021 | May | 50 | 20 | 133 |
| 2022 | Oct | 55 | 40 | 148 |

Comment: Please paste the dataset as copiable text, not as image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go step by step: First you need to go to Power Query Editor, and add an index column. I called it RowID, see the picture below:

[image: Index]

Then Go to your Main Screen and Write this measure:

```
Left Over = CALCULATE(
                    SUMX(Loop, 'Loop'[Created] - 'Loop'[Closed]),
                    FILTER(
                        ALL(Loop),
                        Loop[RowID] <= MAX(Loop[RowID])
                    )
)
```

Now If you test it on a visual by placing the fields in suitable places:

[image: FullSet]